# How much time does a journal editor spend on a submited paper before deciding to either go forward with reviewing or desk rejection?

Tags: journals, paper-submission, editors, journal-workflow

I've been wondering, how much time journal editors spend (on average) on newly submitted papers before deciding go/no-go ?

Do editors have the time to read the full paper or do they get a "feel" of it by reading the title+abstract+conclusion + maybe a few figures ?

It would be very interesting to get answers from people that are currently journal editors to explain what is the typical workflow and time dedicated to newly submitted papers.

Comment: Which journal?  I suspect at most journals it is less than one minute since they almost never desk reject.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist It's true that I should have specified the journal category: all except predatory journals.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist: I'm wondering how field-dependent the claim that most journals almost never desk reject is. In pure math I'd say that desk rejections are not uncommon.

Comment: @JochenGlueck, yes I am mathematics doctor student and quite few times my papers didn't not pass to review process through the editorial scrutiny

Comment: The _American Mathematical Monthly_ does an "editorial review" before sending it to a referee. Sometimes (often?) it is rejected at that stage, with some terse comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on the editor. Some spend more time, some spend less. Those who handle more papers usually spend less. Those who handle one paper every three months usually spend more. There's also a personal element in that some editors have a higher bar before saying a paper is reviewable, while others have a lower bar. For example, it's possible an editor goes "This abstract is not well written, which does not inspire confidence. [Quick glance at main text] Yeah paper is not well written. We can't be sending poorly-written papers for review. Desk reject." A different editor might feel this is overly harsh to the authors, especially if they're not native English speakers, and try harder to understand the paper.

Also one needs to identify appropriate reviewers before sending a manuscript for review, and to do that one needs to have some idea what the paper is about, which means reading it. So actually sending a paper for review can take a while, even if it's clear that the paper is worth sending for review.

Personally, I usually spend less than 10 minutes, but I handle 30+ papers at any one time. Those who handle one paper every three months might spend several hours per paper, based on how fast they respond to emails.

Answer (score 1):

Editors might not even see a desk-rejected paper, as they have trusted graduate students doing most of these rejections. These are just obvious, and result from a completely inappropriate topic to not being formatted according to the journal's template (though the latter ones are not being final).

An associate editor can also desk-reject and sometimes the decision is explicitly left to them. In this case, the editor just looked at the paper long enough to decide on the associate editor. The editor can ask the associate editor to see whether this should go to reviewers or not.

Comment: Could you specify the field which your expierence refers to, in particular the sentence "not being formatted according to the journal's template"? I almost never format articles according to the journal template (if one exists, which is not always the case), but nobody has ever complained to me about it. My field is mathematical analysis (a bit more on the theoretical rather than the applied side).

Comment: computer science

Comment: @JochenGlueck, same. I never format a paper before submitting to journal. If the journal accept for publication then it is obvious they will give directions to format in their way before publication

Comment: Conventions differ. Math is less stringent, but formats are important when there is a page limit.